# Copy entire SVN Log

Tags: svn, project-management, tortoisesvn

IM running tortoise SVN on windows and was wondering is there a way to print out the entire SVN log so that I could paste it into a word document?

Comment: I have a question, though: what exactly do you want to copy? Only the revisions or the files under each revision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on your repository, select TortoiseSVN, Show log.

Click the Show All button so that all the entries are shown.

Select all the logs, right-click, copy to clipboard or Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 1):

You can just select the Logs and hit Crtl+C.